# How to cancel Indexing of a Solr document using Update Request Processor

Tags: java, plugins, solr, indexing

Hi guy iam facing a situation where I shouldn't index document where unwanted content figure. in my situation i want to use a file that containts blacklisted words. so when a document is submited to Solr to the index process. **Solr** should verify that the document contains unwanted content (blacklist keywords) before storing that document into the indexes. there is no an implementation of blacklisting before indexing process that i found on **SOLR**.

So i want to develop a java class that extends UpdateRequestProcessor. there is no documentation that comment the purpose of the UpdateRequestProcessor Methods.

i think that i should implement de blacklisting logic investigation in **processAdd(AddUpdateCommand cmd)** method after that what code should i include to cancel de document that match the blacklist keyword?

```
public class BlackListUpdateRequestProcessor extends UpdateRequestProcessor{

public BlackListUpdateRequestProcessor(UpdateRequestProcessor next) {
    super(next);
}

@Override
public void finish() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finish();
}

@Override
public void processAdd(AddUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    // blacklist investigation logic
    // cancel indexing code here. how to do that?
    super.processAdd(cmd);
}

@Override
public void processCommit(CommitUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.processCommit(cmd);
}

@Override
public void processDelete(DeleteUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.processDelete(cmd);
}

@Override
public void processMergeIndexes(MergeIndexesCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.processMergeIndexes(cmd);
}

@Override
public void processRollback(RollbackUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.processRollback(cmd);
}
```

}

thanks!

Comment: just don't call `super.processAdd()` method if the blacklist logic returns true

Comment: thanks @sidgate added some trivial blaclist investigation code and it works!. Now i have to refine my code...;

Comment: @sidgate Add it as an answer so it can be accepted. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `super.processAdd` method if the blacklist logic returns true

```
@Override
public void processAdd(AddUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    if(!blacklistService.isBlackListed(cmd.getSolrInputDocument())){
       super.processAdd(cmd);
    }
}
```